# How do I use forall or an aggregator in the objective function?

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a decision variable x[i,j] which is 1 or 0 where I want to maximize the sum of each row. I want to use something like forall but it seems like it will only let me use that in the constraints. Is there a way to use it for the objective function too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/tlr_opl_forall.html states, `forall` only works for constraints.

But you could use something like

```
dvar float obj;

maximize obj;
subject to
{
   forall (...) obj == sum(...);
}
```

This would allow you to put constraints on the value of the `obj` variable so that it represents whatever you're interested in.

Comment: The `forall` kind of objective function is nonlinear. This is a simple and nice linearization method.